# python cgal bindings on windows problems

Tags: python, windows, swig, cgal

i'm a python noob - so maybe it is something simple - and please be patient ;-)

i'm stuck to get the cgal bindings running:

so i what i did so far:

- installed/built cgal 5.1.1 and boost 1.74 using vcpkg
- downloaded swig 4.0.2 and made the system path.
- then i followed this: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/Installation

as a difference i did the cmake with the gui and then i compiled everything with visual studio.
there were some warnings, but no errors and it generated a folder with many *py, *pyd, *cxx files and a release folder with *lib and *exp files

when i now try test.py from the example folder i get:

C:\Dev\cgal-swig-bindings\examples\python>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in 
from CGAL import CGAL_Triangulation_3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CGAL'

which somehow makes sense, as i never told python about the new stuff

so i copied test.py into the folder with the generated files [folder with generated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtxKU.png)
i get the same message...

i also tried pip install cgal-bindings. but it can't find CGAL (and other stuff...) altough i think i generated the path variable...

any hints on what i do wrong?
how can i get python to find the modules? (i also generated a system variable "PYTHONPATH" pointing at "C:\Dev\cgal-swig-bindings\build\CGAL-5.1.1_release\build-python\CGAL" - no difference)

Comment: Did you try `C:\Dev\cgal-swig-bindings\build\CGAL-5.1.1_release\build-python` as `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: awesome - now it works! thanks a lot! Thought i tried everything for the paths...